# Do we really need so many user-defined custom tags about (custom|user-defined)[-data]-type[s]?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The following tags exist:

- [custom-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-type) (no tag wiki, 145 questions)
- [custom-data-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/custom-data-type) (no tag wiki, 201 questions)
- [user-defined-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-defined-types) (tag wiki [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/user-defined-types/info), 758 questions)
- [user-defined-data-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-defined-data-types) (no tag wiki, 41 questions)

I don't really see a difference between them. Since [user-defined-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-defined-types) is the most active one, maybe the others should become synonyms?

Comment: "Do we need so many (custom|user-defined)[-data]-type[s]?" :)

Comment: On a more serious note, they all look like duplicates of one tag - the one you mentioned, and the only one that has a wiki. The rest are definitely candidates for being made synonyms of the former.

Comment: That title is missing a Regex.

Comment: Arghh!   The StackOverflow analog to Godwins Law ... is that eventually someone will ask for a solution using a Regex.

Comment: Please add start and end anchors, this is a top priority! :D

Comment: These tags are not our [\*type\*].

Comment: So, I reviewed some questions and was not surprised to find python questions without the python tag and crapshot tags where the asker basically adds as many tags as possible. I don't see any benefit to these tags other than wasting tag space that could prevent people from not using the correct ones.

Comment: What does "user defined type" even mean? The wiki writeup is really bad: "User-Defined Type (UDT) is a type that customize by user. And also called as User-Defined Data Type in database management systems. It's usually used for making some integrations and applying standards. Some related systems are SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, C++, Visual Basic and etc." If this is a database term it should be removed from non-database questions. If the scope includes "C++, Visual Basic, and etc." then it's hopelessly broad and should be culled.

Comment: @JohnKugelman maybe the `[user-defined]` tag can help? :-)